# Sentence without verb in german

Tags: sentence-structure

> alle Übungen online verfügbar

Is this sentence correct without verb? It is form Advertisement

Comment: Look at your title -- it's also perfectly fine without a verb! :)

Comment: Wenn es ein ganzer Satz sein soll, beginnt er mit einem Großbuchstaben und endet mit einem Satzzeichen.

Comment: Funktioniert auch im Imperativ: Alle Macht den Verben! Diese Art von satzwertigen Ausdrücken hat doch inzwischen sicher einen Namen.

Comment: It is correct. But it is not a sentence. :-)

Comment: What is it called, Phrase?

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you if there are grammatical rules that make this legitimate, but I can tell you that your *feeling* is right. Usually you say:

> Alle Übungen *sind* online verfügbar

In some cases it sounds fine to drop the verb *when* it's between a subject and an adjective. But this is only applied to short sentences, e.g. for advertisements. Maybe it gets clearer when you see the english translation:

> All exercises available online

---

*FYI:* Anyways, this is more of a *feels/sounds right* thing and depends on context. Just use verbs, which is formally correct, and be on the safe side.